# jQuery on click fire second child

Tags: jquery, click, parent

I'm trying to make a div have an on click function that opens the link assigned to an `<a>`  inside of it. I've tried a few variations of this, but nothing seems to be working correctly.

My jQuery

```
$('div#task_list').delegate("div.task_bucket", "click", function() {
  $(this + ' div.task_name a.show_task_link').click();
})
```

And my HTML

```
<div class="grid_3 border_box task_bucket">
  <div class="date border_box">
    November 16, 2012
    <span class="comments">3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="task_name">
    <a href="/tasks/165" class="show_task_link" data-remote="true" id="165">Lorem Ipsum Dolor sit amen...</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `this` as the context

```
$('div.task_name a.show_task_link',this).click();
```

Comment: I tried that variation with no luck. I'm using a ruby on rails remote => true link, so I wonder if that's causing some problems, though I wouldn't think so.

Comment: I found some other JS that was interfering, this solution worked the best. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest, given that this seems required to open a new page (since the `href` isn't preceded by a `#` character, that would suggest moving within the current page):

```
$('#task_list').on('click', 'a', function(e){
    window.location = e.target.href;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `$('.task_name a').click()​`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.tlist').click(function(){

var x= $('div.tlist').find('a').attr('href');
 window.open(x);

 });
```

Use find method to get the child attribute..